# Removing datetime gaps in python candlestick intraday chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to remove gaps in my intraday candlestick charts.

However, after looking through most pages here, I am still unable to fully do it.

```
import mpl_finance as mplf
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_chart_minute(ticker,starttime=2,endtime=1,title="Missing"):
days=starttime-endtime
x = starttime
y = endtime
start = today - BDay(x)
end = today - BDay(y)
start = start.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
end = end.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

df = pd.read_csv('filefrom ticker.csv')
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df=df[(df['Datetime'] > start) & (df['Datetime'] < end)]
daters=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df['Datetime']= mdates.date2num(list(df['Datetime']))
dates=list(df['Datetime'])

o=list(df['open'])
c=list(df['close'])
h=list(df['high'])
l=list(df['low'])

quotes = [tuple([dates[i],o[i],c[i],h[i],l[i]]) for i in range(len(dates))]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
mplf.candlestick_ochl(ax1, quotes, width=0.6/(24*60), colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=0.8)

plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Data for ' + str(days) + ' in ' + str(ticker[1:]))
plt.tight_layout()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

I would like the above code to result in a continuous candlestick chart without the gaps in the output which can be seen below.

[image: Please see output here]

Comment: update question with More info like expected output and current output...

Comment: I have added an image of the output I get now, it should be clear from that I believe

Comment: `candlestick_ochl2` should be the version without explicit dates, i.e. plotting everything against the index of the data.